# Отсечение текста за пределы границы таблицы в Word

Tags: office

Есть таблица в Word. Ячейки жестко заданы по высоте и ширине. При наполнении ячейки текстом, текст уходит в вниз. Надо чтобы уходил в право. Как надо настроить таблицу, чтобы лишний текст уходил вправо?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Надо выделить ячейку, перейти в раздел "Абзац" и поставить отступ справа отрицательное значение.